# How to I send a modified variable as the second parameter of a function in Smarty 2?

Tags: php, smarty2

I have this code which works perfectly in my template:

```
{php}
    echo date("F j, Y | g:iA",strtotime($this->_tpl_vars['eventObj']->get_evt_starttime()));
{/php}
```

I want to write the same thing without PHP tags. I know that `{$eventObj|strtotime}` will send `eventObj` to `strtotime`", but how do I sent the result of this to `date` as the second parameter?

I couldn't find anything in the docs on sending the result of a modifier as the second parameter of another modifier. I could only find applying two modifiers to the same thing.

I tired putting parentheses and playing with the colon syntax but it wouldn't work. I need to just ask someone.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**in php**

```
$smarty->assign('time', "2012-01-01 01:01");
```

**in smarty template**

```
{$time|strtotime|date_format:"%B %e, %Y | %H:%m %p"}
```

**output**

```
January  1, 2012 | 01:01 AM
```